# Yii2: How to override the yii\db\Query class to add default conditions with queries

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I want to make a cloud-based application where I store the application id and `branch_id` in session and I want to add the `application_id` and `branch_id` to each DB query.

Easy I am  overriding  the `find()` using

```
    public static function find()
{
    return parent::find()->where([]);
}
```

But the issue is how i override the query like this

```
  $total_return_price = (new Query())
            ->select('SUM(product_order.order_price * product_order.quantity) as return_price')
            ->from('order')
            ->innerJoin('product_order', 'product_order.order_id = order.id')
            ->where(['=', 'order.user_id', $user_id])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'order.status', '4'])
            ->one();
```

Comment: You can change that query with activeQuery and write like this
`Order::find()->select('SUM(product_order.order_price * 
product_order.quantity) as return_price')
->innerJoin('product_order', 'product_order.order_id = order.id')
            ->where(['=', 'order.user_id', $user_id])
            ->andWhere(['=', 'order.status', '4'])
            ->one();`

Comment: Thak u for your response.There are more the 200 different type of queries in the application.i can not use this in each query.

Comment: just tell me please how i can overide the each query to db using activeRecord class

Comment: The answer is: you can't. An option is to override `Query` class by **`DependencyInjection`**

Comment: @Yupik..how i can use DependencyInjection?

Comment: [Yii2 - Dependency Injection Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html)

Comment: Hey did the answer worked out for you do select if it helped you somehow. Thanks

Comment: just updated the answer see if it fixes the issue @Sajid

Comment: hey @Sajid i noticed you took back your upvote on my answer was there ay problem you faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one way is to extend the `Query` class and override the traits `where()` `from()` and `select()` and change the namespace from the `yii\db\Query` to `common\components\Query` overall in the models where you want the condition to be added. But remember it is your responsibility to make sure all those tables have these 2 fields (`application_id` and `branch_id`) inside the tables where ever you replace the `yii\db\Query` with `common\components\Query`.

Why override `where()` `from()` and `select()` ? you have the possibility of writing queries in the following formats.

Let's say we have a  `product` table with the fields `id` and `name`, now consider the following queries.

```
$q->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->all ();

$q->select ( '*' )
        ->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->all ();

$q->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->where ( [ 'name' => '' ] )
        ->all ();

$q->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->andWhere ( [ 'name' => '' ] )
        ->all ();

$q->select ( '*' )
        ->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->where ( [ 'IN' , 'id' , [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 89 , 0 ] ] )
        ->andwhere ( [ 'name' => '' ] )
        ->all ();


$q->select ( '*' )
        ->from ( '{{product}}' )
        ->where ( [ 'and' ,
        [ 'IN' , 'id' , [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 89 , 0 ] ] ,
        [ 'name' => '' ]
        ] )
        ->all();
```

The above will generate the following SQL queries

```
SELECT * FROM `product` 
SELECT * FROM `product` 
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`name`='') 
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`name`='')
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 89, 0)) AND (`name`='')
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 89, 0)) AND (`name`='')
```

So you need to add all the above queries with two where conditions by default

create a file name `Query` inside the **`common/components`** and add the following,

> Note: I have added conditions with hardcoded values for the columns
>   like this `[ 'application_id' => 1 ] , [ 'branch_id' => 1 ]` replace
>   them with the respective variables from the session before actually using
>   it for testing purpose you can keep as is.I assume that you want the above two 
>   fields to be added with an `and` condition in the query.

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use yii\db\Query as BaseQuery;

class Query extends BaseQuery {

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $condition
     * @param type $params
     * @return $this
     */
    public function where( $condition , $params = array() ) {
        parent::where ( $condition , $params );

        $defaultConditionEmpty = !isset ( $this->where[$this->from[0] . '.company_id'] );

        if ( $defaultConditionEmpty ) {
            if ( is_array ( $this->where ) && isset ( $this->where[0] ) && strcasecmp ( $this->where[0] , 'and' ) === 0 ) {
                $this->where = array_merge ( $this->where , [ [ $this->from[0] . '.company_id' => 1 ] , [ $this->from[0] . '.branch_id' => 1 ] ] );
            } else {
                $this->where = [ 'and' , $this->where , [ $this->from[0] . '.company_id' => 1 ] , [ $this->from[0] . '.branch_id' => 1 ] ];
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $tables
     * @return $this
     */
    public function from( $tables ) {
        parent::from ( $tables );
        $this->addDefaultWhereCondition ();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Private method to add the default where clause 
     */
    private function addDefaultWhereCondition() {
        if ( $this->from !== null ) {

            $this->where = [ 'and' ,
                [ $this->from[0] . '.company_id' => 1 ] , [ $this->from[0] . '.branch_id' => 1 ]
            ];
        }
    }

}
```

Now to test it create a test action inside your `SiteController` like below and access it

```
public function actionTest() {
        $q = new \common\components\Query();

        echo $q->from ( '{{product}}' )->createCommand ()->rawSql;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $q->select ( '*' )->from ( '{{product}}' )->createCommand ()->rawSql;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $q->from ( '{{product}}' )->where ( [ 'name' => '' ] )->createCommand ()->rawSql;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $q->from ( '{{product}}' )->andWhere ( [ 'name' => '' ] )->createCommand ()->rawSql;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $q->select ( '*' )->from ( '{{product}}' )->where ( [ 'IN' , 'id' , [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 89 , 0 ] ] )->andwhere ( [ 'name' => '' ] )->createCommand ()->rawSql;

        echo "<br />";
        echo $q->select ( '*' )->from ( '{{product}}' )
                ->where ( [ 'and' ,
                    [ 'IN' , 'id' , [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 89 , 0 ] ] ,
                    [ 'name' => '' ]
                ] )
                ->createCommand ()->rawSql;
        return;
    }
```

Do not worry about the `product` table we need to check the query generated so we are not executing the query instead using `->createCommand()->rawSql` to print the query built. so access the above action it should now print you the queries with both the columns added like below

```
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1)
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1)
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`name`='') AND (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1)
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1) AND (`name`='')
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 89, 0)) AND (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1) AND (`name`='')
SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE (`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 89, 0)) AND (`name`='') AND (`application_id`=1) AND (`branch_id`=1)
```

Hope that helps you out or someone else looking for the same solution

**EDIT**

I updated the class above and added the fix to the queries using joins, that throws an error

> Column 'company_id' in where clause is ambiguous

I have added the first `table` name available in the `from` array as all your tables have the field name and adding the condition for the first selected table will work as it would be joined with the next table with `ON` condition. 
And I have removed the `select()` trait override from the class as we won't be needing it.

Comment: Thnak you for kind response.

Comment: Can you please help that how i can remove the ambiguous in where clause.waitng for your rsponse..

Comment: i could not understand what you meant by **ambiguous in where clause** @Sajid can you pleasae elaborate

Comment: sir the application_id and branch_id is in all the tables it is ok without join .the join query retrun ambigious error..its mean the query is confused wwith same attribut in both table return error

Comment: hmm... let me test it with join and  i will reply back @Sajid

Comment: i think we need to overide the core files of vendors .the ambigious error is always create the problem in normal search model also

Comment: the search model has no link with it as it is a separate component and would effect only those queries that are using `common\components\Query` and not your normal search models.

Comment: i mean the ambigious error occur when we use the join in search model if there any attribute has same name,for that error we just use alias('a') and name the attribute on one table as a.id.

Comment: The SQL being executed was: SELECT `users_level`.`display_name` AS `current_level` FROM `user` INNER JOIN `users_level` ON user.user_level_id = users_level.id WHERE (`user`.`id` = '6691BCEE-EFAF-4862-8C4D-8FC510B7547E') AND (`company_id`='F9E7025A-47B1-4D52-A73B-C1D83E0F4DD0') AND (`branch_id`='464C2FFD-B0BD-4C91-B482-34B1F82EEB42')
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1052
    [2] => Column 'company_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: i replaced application_id wwith company_id

Comment: So in the condition of  using `join` the ambiguity can be removed by using table name along with the field name and we can use the first table available in the `from` array , i will update the answer in a moment @Sajid

Comment: Done it @Muhammad Omer Aslam. Well done and thankx lot

Comment: Now for all simple find method,i mean find() i am using this one

Comment: public static function find()
    {
        return parent::find()->where(['=', 'company_id',Yii::$app->session['company_id']])->andWhere(['=','branch_id',Yii::$app->session['branch_id']]);
    }

Comment: in all other models its working ok now the proble is when ever user vaidate for login it return validation flase becauser of this static method

Comment: i think you should add a separate question for the issue so that the problem is segregated and a solution specific to this section should be suggested add the question with the related code and just add a message here for me i will look into it @Sajid

Comment: I have created the Question and tag you in the comment .i dont know exactily that u hae recived the notification or not due to name space there. here is the question link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49317648/how-to-over-ride-the-find-method-for-each-model-in-yii2

Comment: yeah i got it @Sajid give me some time i will reply there

Comment: thank you no problem sir..Its difficult to get help in this frame work.so thank u so much sir