# Yii2 Override find() to add default condition globally

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have to override the method using

```
namespace common\models;
use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;

class Addfindcondition extends ActiveQuery
{

    public function init()
    {

        $this->andOnCondition([$this->modelClass::tableName() . '.branch_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id ]);
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

And call the method in each model separately like this

```
public static function find()
{
    return new Addfindcondition(get_called_class());
}
```

Now I want to override the find method globally. How it is possible that I dont need to use this static method in each model

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Comment: what are you overriding here, are you trying to add the 2 conditions by default in `ActiveRecord` models as you did for `yii\db\Query`

Comment: yes Sir same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the `find()` method in case of `ActiveRecord` models, as you need to add this for all models you should create a BaseModel say

**`common\components\ActiveRecord`** or inside your models if you like

```
<?php
namespace common\components;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord as BaseActiveRecord;

class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord{
    public static function find() {
       return parent::find ()
        ->onCondition ( [ 'and' ,
            [ '=' , static::tableName () . '.application_id' , 1 ] ,
            [ '=' , static::tableName () . '.branch_id' , 2 ]
        ] );
    }
}
```

And then extend all your models where you need to add this condition to the `find()` method, replace `yii\db\ActiveRecord` to `common\components\ActiveRecord` for instance if I have a `Product` Model and I want to add the conditions to it by default I will change the model from

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

class Product extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {
```

to

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

class Product extends common\components\ActiveRecord{
```